# W3C - ID Tag for <style>

Tags: html, w3c

is this allowed?

```
<style id="my_id_0" type="text/css"> ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which markup language you are using.

- It is not allowed in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html).
- It is allowed in [XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-transitional.dtd_style) (this looks like one of many changes that the working group decided to implement without a mention in the differences from HTML 4.01 section)
- It is allowed in the [HTML 5 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-transitional.dtd_style) it is allowed but how it is actually supported by browsers (especially when the style-tag is used within the head) is another question.

Answer (score -3):

Not allowed according to [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_style.asp). Just wrap your `<style>` tag with `<span></span>`

Comment: It is invalid for the `style` tag to appear anywhere except in `head`.

Comment: W3Schools is **not** the W3C